# How to retrieve SSH Fingerprint on HDInsight cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I have created an HDInsight cluster and provided my ssh public key when the cluster was created.

When I try to ssh into the cluster, I'm asked to verify the cluster's SSH Fingerprint:

```
user:~ me$ ssh 
sshuser@myclusterr-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
The authenticity of host 'myclusterr-ssh.azurehdinsight.net (1.2.3.4)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:c+L/1234567890abcdefghijklmnop/1234.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

With Azure VM's, I can run `ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` from a Command Script to output the signature:

[image]

Is there something similar I can do on HDInsight clusters to retrieve the cluster SSH Fingerprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did the following:

- Connect using Zeppelin
- Create a new notebook using the `sh` interpreter
- Run: `ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`

[image]